# How to find something from a file in a nother file batch

Tags: batch-file

How can i find a whole text file in another fext file?
here is my examlpe in a code:

```
echo 1 > t.txt
echo 1 > e.txt
echo 2 >> e.txt
findstr t.txt e.txt
if %errorlevel% equ 0 echo found!
::or
comp t.txt e.txt
if %errorlevel% equ 0 echo found!
pause
```

Lets say that every computer on a network needs to write "wmic bios get serialnumber > t.txt" And to find a specific computer on the network we have e.txt which contains the serialnumber of the computer we need to find. How do we find the one serialnumber in t.txt?

Comment: What's the finality of this code ? You have `fc`to compare 2 files

Comment: You want to find the contents of an entire `multi-line file` within another text file right?  You example code shows `t.txt` with a single line, but from your dysfunctional code it looks like you are trying to find the contents of `t.txt within e.txt` - which can work with the correct syntax if `t.txt` only contains keywords to find.  Improve your question with written explanation if I'm on the wrong track.

Comment: how big are the files?

Comment: foxidrive, i am amazed by how smart people are on this site, you are a genius. thank you for your time. i will try with fc

Comment: Lets say that every computer on a network needs to write "wmic bios get serialnumber > t.txt" 
And to find a specific computer on the network we have e.txt which contains the serialnumber of the computer we need to find.

How do we find the one serialnumber in t.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous comments I think you want not to "find a whole text file in another text file", but precisely the opposite thing: "How to convert the multi-line output of `wmic` to just one line, so it can be found with `findstr`?". The Batch file below do that:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "line="
for /F %%a in ('wmic bios get serialnumber') do (
   set "line=!line!%%a "
)
echo !line:~0,-3!>> t.txt
```

Output example:

```
SerialNumber 5CG24423TQ
```